# Can't install pytorch 1.13.1 in airflow 2.2.5

Tags: docker, pytorch, airflow

I am trying to install pytorch 1.13.1 in [airflow-2.2.5](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/2.2.5-python3.9/images/sha256-5aa3cb42ecc68da78f6b77203472e7fdbad36d4a2c979e7f4486ac2988ab6a7c?context=explore) docker image via a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.5-python3.9

ARG AIRFLOW_HOME_ARG=/opt/airflow
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_HOME_ARG}

# A trick to make image building functional both on macOS, as well as, other unix based systems
# Create airflow group and user as root then switch to airflow user
USER root
RUN groupadd -r airflow
USER airflow
# each folder in AIRFLOW_HOME can be used as import in python
ENV PYTHONPATH ${AIRFLOW_HOME}:$PYTHONPATH
# install extra requirements
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --user --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt
```

where `requirements.txt` contains line:

```
pytorch==1.13.1
```

I have 64 bit version of python. When I try to build the image, I get

> #15 1.263 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch~=1.13.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 1.0.2)
> #15 1.263 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch~=1.13.1

What was also tried:

1. Using [2.7.1-python3.9](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/2.7.1-python3.9/images/sha256-6c1b8fa356f016ec6a45e9de635a6e54b0d39c20b3877945e7a3670f743ab2dc?context=explore)
2. Using [2.7.1-python3.11](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/2.7.1-python3.11/images/sha256-e10b549b0b84c1ed7177349edf80f4b782f528b69a1afebf6aa79177ac89b158?context=explore)

As one can see the target version is seen within the torch wheel list: [torch-1.13.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/).

Whatever I try I am not able to see any other version than *0.1.2, 1.0.2*. How can I install pytorch 1.13.1 in apache/airflow:2.2.5-python3.9?

Comment: "I am trying to install pytorch 1.13.1", you should specify *how*.

Comment: The latest stable version of Pytorch is 2.0.1.  Is it acceptable for you?  Is v1.13.1 a mandatory requirement?

Comment: Rename your library to `torch==1.13.1`, `pytorch` is only accessible till 1.0.2 version

Comment: @Pino Unfortunately no, that will break a lot of things.

Comment: @sann05 Thanks, renaming to torch worked out :)